# How do I query CloudWatch metrics for ALL (1000+) EC2 instances that ran during a specified timeframe with Boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to query CloudWatch metrics for all EC2 instances in my account (1000+) that reported them during a specific 1 hour time frame (load test) using Boto3. It is expected that instances would have been brought up/down by auto-scaling during the test.

I've tried using search expression as suggested in [this StackOverflow answer for querying RDS instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56593570/fetch-aws-cloudwatch-metrics-for-all-rds-instance-using-wildcard/56597261#56597261), but this is limited to 500 results with no way to paginate according to the [CloudWatch search expression syntax docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/search-expression-syntax.html):

> **Search expression limits**
>
> The maximum search expression query size is 1024 characters. You can have as many as 100 search expressions on one graph. A graph can display as many as 500 time series.

I could do multiple queries for metrics by specifying instance ids using something like this:

```py
for instance_id in instance_ids:
    response = boto3.client("cloudwatch").get_metric_data(
        MetricDataQueries=[
            {
                'Id': "network_out",
                'MetricStat': {
                    'Metric': {
                        'Namespace':
                            "AWS/EC2",
                        'MetricName':
                            'NetworkOut',
                        'Dimensions': [{
                            'Name': 'InstanceId',
                            'Value': instance_id
                        }]
                    },
                    'Period': 300,
                    'Stat': 'Sum',
                    'Unit': 'Bytes'
                }
                'ReturnData': True
            }
        ]
    )
```

but I would still need to have the full list of `instance_ids` that reported metrics during the time frame, **including those which were terminated by auto-scaling.**

How can I query CloudWatch metrics for **all** EC2 instances which reported during the time frame?

A way to get a list of all EC2 instances which reported metrics during that time frame would also work.